# Timer doesn't start after midnight

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have two timers. One of then run every 5min and the other is 10min. Once I run the application it works perfectly but after 11:50 it stops executing.

My code is as below :

```
//At minute 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, and 55 past every hour from 0 through 4 and every hour.

for(int hrsTime=1;hrsTime<=4;hrsTime++){
    System.out.println("hours start time : "+hrsTime);
    _log.info("MrkRomeFiles hours start time : "+hrsTime);
    start_1=0;
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrsTime);//everyday 1,2,3 and 4 oclock
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, start_1);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        timer.schedule( new MrkRomeFiles(_env), today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));                      

        System.out.println("minuts start time : "+start_1);                 
        _log.info("MrkRomeFiles minuts start time : "+start_1);

        start_1=start_1+5;  
    }
}       

//At minute 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, and 55 past every hour from 8 through 23 every hour.
for(int startTime=8;startTime<=23;startTime++){
    int start=0;
    System.out.println("hours start time : "+startTime);
    _log.info("MrkRomeFiles hours start time : "+startTime);
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){                          
        System.out.println("minuts start time : "+start);                       
        _log.info("MrkRomeFiles minuts start time : "+start);
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startTime);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, start);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);                      
        timer.schedule(new MrkRomeFiles(_env), today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
        start=start+5;  
    }
}

//this is for run every 10min
for(int startTime=0;startTime<=23;startTime++){
    _log.info("oracle hour time :  : "+startTime);
    System.out.println("oracle hour time : "+startTime);
    int startOraMinutes=0;
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){   
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startTime);
            today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startOraMinutes);
            today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            timer.schedule(new MrkOraFiles(_env), today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));

            _log.info("oracle minuts time : "+startOraMinutes);
            System.out.println("oracle minuts time : "+startOraMinutes);
            startOraMinutes=startOraMinutes+10; 
            }
        }
```

**below are the logs which are printed :**

```
2017-02-28 23:40:00,556 [       MrkRomeFiles.java:Timer-0:600] - mrkRome file start execution at 2017/02/28 23:40:00
2017-02-28 23:40:00,616 [        MrkOraFiles.java:Timer-0:179] - mrkOra file start execution at : 2017/02/28 23:40:00
2017-02-28 23:40:00,627 [        MrkOraFiles.java:Timer-0:179] - mrkOra file start execution at : 2017/02/28 23:40:00
2017-02-28 23:45:00,557 [       MrkRomeFiles.java:Timer-0:600] - mrkRome file start execution at 2017/02/28 23:45:00
2017-02-28 23:50:00,557 [       MrkRomeFiles.java:Timer-0:600] - mrkRome file start execution at 2017/02/28 23:50:00
2017-02-28 23:50:00,617 [        MrkOraFiles.java:Timer-0:179] - mrkOra file start execution at : 2017/02/28 23:50:00
2017-02-28 23:50:00,627 [        MrkOraFiles.java:Timer-0:179] - mrkOra file start execution at : 2017/02/28 23:50:00
```

Comment: Do you run these loops exactly at midnight? Or at any time the application is started?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not simply schedule your tasks for every 5/10 minutes?

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(System.nanoTime());
        }
    };

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
```

Comment: Do your timer tasks finish properly? In the log it only says it started, do you not log finishing times or is it crashing?

Comment: Hi Jure, thanks for reply, i have uploaded code only, is there need to stop timer, please share me some hint